# Jquery and webforms in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Why do people say that there is a problem of using javascript/jquery with webforms, compare mvc?

Cant I just open `<script type="javascript/text"></script>` and do all the javascript there?

also if the the user has got javascript disabled..would the paging in gridview, for example, work?

Also does mvc have all the webform controls (e.g. gridview)? and do you think the future is with mvc?

ps. this site was build with mvc..and its clientside programming is quite impressive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do people say that there is a problem of using javascript/jquery with webforms

People that say this should probably justify their statement.

> Cant I just open `<script type="javascript/text"></script>` and do all the javascript there?

Of course that you can. Well, actually it would be better to put your javascript code into separate javascript files and then reference them from the page.

> also if the the user has got javascript disabled..would the paging in gridview, for example, work?

That will depend on whether you are doing client side or server side paging.

> Also does mvc have all the webform controls (e.g. gridview)?

No, ASP.NET MVC doesn't use server side controls. In ASP.NET MVC you work with Models, Controllers and Views. Inside the views you could use HTML helpers to generate HTML snippets. In ASP.NET MVC 3 there's a built-in WebGrid helper (which IMHO is quite limited). There are also third-party helpers allowing to build grids. For example Telerik provides some nice [ASP.NET MVC extensions](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx) including a grid.

> and do you think the future is with mvc?

Totally off-topic question.

> this site was build with mvc..and its clientside programming is quite impressive

I agree.

Comment: so mvc is perhaps more similar to classic asp, but it has got some business logic...sounds lame, dont you think

Comment: @WithFlyingColors, ASP.NET MVC is a different pattern. I don't want to do any comparisons. It is similar to classic ASP only in the view part where you have more control over the generated markup. I prefer not to discuss lameness on StackOverflow.